# How to retrieve a column value from DESCRIBE DETAIL <table_name>

Tags: databricks, databricks-sql

I would like to use the "Last modified" value from the description of my table in databricks. I know how to get all columns from the table by using "DESCRIBE DETAIL table_name", but I wish to simply get the last modified value since I need to use it in my WHERE comparison

Answer (score 3):

The `DESCRIBE DETAIL` functionality returns a dataframe with 1 row, but isn't handled as a proper table in Spark SQL using databricks as of now, but you can do it via temp view as @axel-r pointed out:

```
df = spark.sql("""DESCRIBE DETAIL  database_name.table_name""")
df.createOrReplaceTempView("details")

%sql
SELECT lastModified FROM details
```

In my case, I wanted the last update date from the `DESCRIBE DETAIL` command, and it happens that `DESCRIBE HISTORY` is treated as a proper table in Spark SQL, and adding `LIMIT 1` shows the [most recent record](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/delta-utility.html#detail-schema&language-sql). You can get the same info that way. The benefit of that is that you can save it as permament view, where in the above method you can't:

```
%sql
SELECT timestamp as lastModified 
FROM (DESCRIBE HISTORY database_name.table_name LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: Thanks. I wonder why DESCRIBE DETAIL and DESCRIBE HISTORY are treated differently in Spark SQL?

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the result of the SQL query as a list and get the content like this :

```py
spark.sql("DESCRIBE DETAIL database_name.table_name").collect()[0]['lastModified']

>>> Out[7]: datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 11, 8, 16, 5)
```